# How do I install a plugin in Audacity installed via snap?

Tags: xubuntu, snap, 18.10, plugins, audacity

I installed the latest Audacity 2.3.1 via snap.
Now I want to install a plugin but as snap creates read-only images, what's the best way to download and install a plugin.

Comment: Typically audacity can use `~/.audacity-files/plugins` to access downloaded plugins. It appears the snap version can't from there or anywhere else. You could start an issue here, https://forum.snapcraft.io/c/snap  The .deb version(s) will work fine wiath plugins

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your other question shows that you are using Ubuntu 18.10.

It has Audacity version 2.2.2 in the [*universe* repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=audacity&searchon=names&suite=cosmic&section=all) - so you can remove snap-based version by

```
snap remove audacity
```

and install deb-packaged with

```
sudo apt-get install audacity
```

and it will not have problems with plugins.

If you need newer version - use some PPA, for example [`ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/audacity`](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntuhandbook1/+archive/ubuntu/audacity?field.series_filter=cosmic):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/audacity
sudo apt-get install audacity
```

as it provides version 2.3.1.